# Check the value of a input type number

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to check a input type number, I don't want it te be < 0.
But my code doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?
Here's my code: (javascript)

```
var valueHours = document.getElementById('txtHours').value;
if (valueHours < 0) {
    alert("Can't be lower than 0"); 
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="txtHours" id="txtHours"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please adjust the quotes in your alert

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var valueHours = document.getElementById('txtHours').value;
  if (parseFloat(valueHours) <=0) {
    alert("Can\'t be lower than 0"); 
    return false;
 }
 else {
   return true;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PZrqJ/)

Comment: Haha, you made two fixes in 1 answer. Either change the double quotes to single, or dont escape the single quote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your alert is wrong:

```
alert('Can't be lower than 0');
```

You can see the colors are wrong. Try this:

```
alert("Can't be lower than 0");
```

I've added the double quotes instead of the single quotes. Please find some documentation about quotes and escaping.

This would work to, but I prefer the double quotes for readability:

```
alert('Can\'t be lower than 0'); // added a slash for the singlequote
```